# Expected both Video and Audio coming from ScreenCaptureKit Framework in Mac OS Development

Tags: macos, screencapturekit

I am referring https://developer.apple.com/documentation/screencapturekit/capturing_screen_content_in_macos

Using this, I have captured video and stored it in a .mov file but am not able to record audio in it. Any ideas?

I have gone through a lot of sample code written around this but have found that video was captured but audio spoken while capturing video was not captured.

Already Referred:
https://github.com/nonstrict-hq/ScreenCaptureKit-Recording-example

Answer (score 1):

Did you check configuration setting?

You have to set capturesAudio flag.

`streamConfiguration.capturesAudio = true`